# Does anyone know why this plot forms bands?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I've plotted the distinct values of $f_n(x)=\pi(x)\pi(n-x),$ for some index on the x-axis. The plot seems to form bands, the most visible one being at the top. $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

> Q: Does anyone know why this occurs?

[image]

Comment: What precisely have you plotted? Did you fix some $n$ and plotted a mark at the point $(k, \pi(k)\pi(n-k))$ for $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n/2$ (or some other upper bound), or is it something else?

Comment: I fixed an $n$ and found all $x$ values and then evaluated those $x$ values in the function, and threw out all duplicates. Then I plotted $(n,d)$ where $d$ is the number values after sieving out the duplicates. Then I did this for $n$ up to $2,500$

Comment: I suppose you're curious why the bands are linear?  The fact that multiple bands exist should be expected when you have a 'stepwise' function of that form.  I would guess that if you take any set with approximately the same distribution as the primes you would get something similar.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you plotted $g$, where $$g(n) = \# \{ \pi(k)\pi(n-k) : 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}\,.$$ Is that right?

Comment: @DanielFischer yep that's right

Comment: By symmetry, $f_n(x) = f_n(n-x)$. Thus we need only consider $x \leqslant n/2$. The value of $f_n$ changes whenever $x$ is a prime or $n - x$ is a prime. Apart from the symmetry, duplication of values is rare. If we ignore that for the moment, $g(n)$ is the number of changes (plus $1$). We get a change for every prime $\leqslant n$, but if $n-p$ is also prime we eat two primes for the change, so essentially you plot $\pi(n) - \frac{1}{2}R_2(n)$, where $R_2(n)$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of two primes (taking order into account, so $3+7 = 10 =7 + 3$ counts as two…

Comment: …representations, and fudging the problem that $R_2(n)$ is odd when $n$ is twice a prime). Since $R_2(2k+1) \in \{0,2\}$, for odd $n$ the value is essentially $\pi(n)$. For even $n$ it's more or less a transformation of [Goldbach's comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_comet) and the bands in your plot correspond to the bands in that. Unless I severely underestimated the occurrences of $f_n(k) = f_n(m)$ for $k < m \leqslant n/2$ with $\pi(m) > \pi(k)$.

Comment: 3rd time this came up so far. for gaps in the primes the same $(a-1)(b+1)=ab+a-b-1$ happens if $ab$ happens as will $ab-b$