# Plotting $g(n,r)-$ the distinct values of a two-dimensional prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, graphing-functions

$\pi(k)$ is the prime counting function.

$$g(n,r) = \# \{ \pi(k)\pi(n-k)\pi(j)\pi(r-j) : 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n,~ 0 \leqslant j \leqslant r\}\,.$$

> I would like to see a plot of $g(n,r).$

Here's a plot of $\pi(k)\pi(j)\pi(7-k)\pi(7-j)$ which implies $g(7,7)=3$ because there are $3$ distinct levels in the plot:

[image]

I've been able to plot $g(n)=\# \{ \pi(k)\pi(n-k): 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$ but am having trouble going up a dimension. I have an idea of what the plot in 3 dimensions should look like but would like to see what it looks like exactly to make sure I have the right idea.

Some context: [Does anyone know why this plot forms bands?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3443701/does-anyone-know-why-this-plot-forms-bands)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to plot $g(n,r)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\pi(k)\,\pi(n-k)\sum\limits_{j=0}^r\pi(j)\,\pi(r-j)$?

Comment: @StevenClark no, I don't want to sum. I want to plot the distinct values of the function for each $n$ and $r$. For a specific example, take $g(11,11).$

Comment: I don't understand. You have 4 variables including n,r, k, and j which would require a 5 dimensional plot.

Comment: For example, $g(7,7)=3$ because there are $3$ distinct values of $\pi(k)\pi(j)\pi(7-k)\pi(7-j)$

Comment: A 3 dimensional plot would work, however, I think it is much simpler to visualize $g(n,r)$ as a 2d square grid with each sub-square coloured according to whether $g(n,r)$ is big or small. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a bit of Python magic (or any other programming language) I have a fix to see the plot that you desire. There's probably a clever-er way to do this, but this is the simplest one I can think of.

Basically, all you need to do is go to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences and find the [sequence of corresponding to the prime counting function](http://oeis.org/A000720). Here you can find the values of $\pi(n)$ for $n\le 78$. Using this list (which you can just copy and paste into Python) you can simply compute all the products $\pi(k)\pi(n-k)\pi(r-j)$ by looping over all $0\le k \le n, 0\le j \le r$, and **put them into a 'set' S**.

By 'set' I mean a set class in Python, which is crucial for it will take care of repeated elements more efficiently than checking wether they're on a list or not. Then you can ask Python to return $size(S)$, the number of elements in the set $S$, and there you have it, the value of $g(n,r)$. You can store these on a $78 \times 78$ matrix, and then plot the height map using Matplotlib or any other of your favourite plotting tool on Python.

This will give you the graph of $g(n,r)$ in the square $[1,78]\times [1,78]$.

If you wanna get a larger square, say $k \times k$, then you can compute $\pi(n)$ for $n\le k$ by yourself by implementing [Erastothenes sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

**EDIT:** If you code up what I mention this is what you get. A plot of $g(n,r)$ for $(n,r) \in [1,78]\times [1,78]$ , where $n$ is in the $x$-axis and $r$ in the $y$-axis. I don't know if it is appropriate to post code in Math StackExchange, so, if you if you're interested in seeing my code feel free to  get in touch.

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$g(n,r)$ for $(n,r) \in [1,78]\times [1,78]$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wv4J.png)